# Convert array to hashmap. How to write better

Tags: javascript

What is best code for conversion

```
[
   {id : 1, payload : "aaa"},
   {id : 1, payload : "bbb"},
   {id : 2, payload : "ccc"}
]
```

to

```
{  
    "1" : [
        {id : 1, payload : "aaa"},
        {id : 1, payload : "bbb"}
    ],
    "2" : [
        {id : 2, payload : "ccc"}
    ]
]
```

?

Variants

```
let res = {}
src.forEach(r=>{
    let id = r.id;
    let arr = res[id];
    if (!arr) {
        res[id] = [];
        arr = res[id];
    }
    arr.push(r);
});
```

In short

```
src.forEach(r=>(res[r.id] || (res[r.id] = [])).push(r));
```

How to remove one `res[r.id]`?

I want something like

```
src.forEach(r=>(res[r.id] ?= []).push(r));
```

inb4: write function

Yes, I can, but it not looks estetic good and question not about only this case.

Comment: I think its not possible. Also you should concentrate on readability of code not on shortening of code.

Comment: Why are you trying to save a few characters? To the interpreter, it won't make a difference. It will just make it hard for anyone else looking at your code. They'll need a second look to understand what's going on.

Comment: Because I'm too lazy to typing null checks every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve this.

```js
const input = [
   {id : 1, payload : "aaa"},
   {id : 1, payload : "bbb"},
   {id : 2, payload : "ccc"}
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr.id]) {
    acc[curr.id].push(curr);
  } else {
    acc[curr.id] = [curr]
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I need set default value and return it, if value is null without repeat his name. Structure path can be long.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get the same group for every same `id`. At the end build a new object.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, payload: "aaa" }, { id: 1, payload: "bbb" }, { id: 2, payload: "ccc" }],
    result = Object.fromEntries([
        ...data.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.id, [...(m.get(o.id) || []), o]), new Map)
    ]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```